# How does Azure Search support Geo-Replicated scenarios?

Tags: azure-search, geo-location

The [setup documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/configure_azure_search) states that:

> "Sitecore supports a Search service with geo-replicated scenarios."

It also mentions that you achieve this by adding multiple `Azure Search` instances in the connectionstring using a pipe separator.

Clearly in `Azure Portal` you would set each search instance to be in the desired region during setup.

Other than that does anyone know how region selection is supported under the hood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Search has no built in replication at this time. The Sitecore Azure Search Provider can be pointed to multiple Azure Search instance at once and it will mirror all Create, Update, Delete, requests to those additional instances.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore supports a Search service with geo-replicated scenarios. To use this type of scenario:

Create two or more Search service instances.

[image]

Add connection strings with a pipe separator (|). If you have two search services, for example, searchservice1 and searchservice2, and you want to use them in a geo-replicated scenario, you must use the following connection string:

```
<add name="cloud.search" connectionString="serviceUrl=https://searchservice1.search.windows.net;apiVersion=2015-02-28;apiKey=AdminKey1|serviceUrl=https://searchservice2.search.windows.net;apiVersion=2015-02-28;apiKey=AdminKey2" />
```

All details are int the link you provide.

Comment: Azure Search has no built in replication at this time. The Sitecore Azure Search Provider can be pointed to multiple Azure Search instance at once and it will mirror all Create, Update, Delete, requests to those additional instances.

Comment: @TamasVargaSitecore: You might want to add this as a separate answer. The one here from Vlad is good but does not answer the question (how it works under the hood). What you have put here looks like a more direct answer to the question.